# Redirection to thank you page after submission of contact form in drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to redirect to thank you page after successful submission of contact form in drupal

Looking forward for appropriate solutions asap

Comment: have you tried using `drupal_goto` function mate..??

Comment: Thanks Outlooker but can you please share sample code snippet for redirection to thank you page after submission of contact form

Comment: are you writing a custom module for this contact form..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this with code:

I would set `$form_state['redirect']` in the submit handler.

You can set an additional submit handler for the form using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

See this page on [drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)